# file upload using react-step-builder form with multiple pages

Tags: reactjs

i am using react hook form to create a from with multiple pages

i am able to create it and it working with all filed except   `file-input-type` how do i pass i file from another page and finaly pass it to api in the final page
i a have actualy 3 pages i have only added the 1st and final page (fist page has the file input filed and final page has the api to which it must be submitted)

form with `file upload field`

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
export default function Form(props) {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();


 <input style={styles.file}  type="file" />
          </div>
          <input {...register("name", { required: true })}
            name="husband"
            value={props.getState("name")}
            onChange={props.handleChange}
            style={styles.input}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Name"
          />

 <input onClick={handleSubmit(props.next)}
              type="submit"
              value="Next"
            />
```

form with submit button and api to which it must be uploaded

```
 const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  const submitValue = (e) => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    props.state.patient = "true";

    const data = props.state;

    axios
      .post("registration/", data)
      .then(() => {
        alert("updated data");
        window.location = "/clogin";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        //var my_obj_str = JSON.stringify(error.response.data);
        alert(JSON.stringify(error.response.data));
      });
  };
```

codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-worker-zicnr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: How do you navigate between the page? react-router Link? `a` tags?

Comment: i use react-step-builder

Comment: <Steps config={config}>
              <Step component={Form} />
              <Step component={Form2} />
              <Step component={Form3} />
            </Steps>

Comment: A solution could be managing the entire wizard's state in the parent component. Initiate a state, something like `formState` and pass the `setFormState` function to its children. For every change, the child calls `setFormState` including the file input. The last step will accept also `onFinish` so the parent is the one who calls to the server.

Comment: pls show a example

Comment: @MoshFeu i have added my full code in codesandbox  pls check ur answer and that is entirly differnt

Comment: i have input for file in line number 117 of form.js

Comment: I understand that it's different because you are using multiple forms. I'm suggesting to use a single form to make it easier to handle the data in one place - the parent component.

Comment: thats not possible beacese i have already complted the project and convertiong this form to single form will cause me lot of othere changes to make @MoshFeu

Comment: I updated my answer - added an example and a demo for forms in each step

Comment: @MoshFeu i cant do as u have given  it not pratical for me to change every css  that i have already done by changing into single js file can pls edit the code sandbox and make it work thanku

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240950/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-meon).

Comment: @MoshFeu         pls help me fix it in multiple files i have to complte this by today if i have to split it into multiple compoents it will take time to change the ui

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options

#### Single `form` wraps all the steps

You can wrap the `<Steps />` component with one `form`. Make the `<Step />`s components stateless that accepts `onInputChange` which will called upon input changes.
`onInputChange` call [`setValue`](https://react-hook-form.com/faqs#question6) to update the form's state.

When the form submitted, you have the file (among other inputs) so you can send it to the server.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Steps, StepsProvider, useSteps } from "react-step-builder";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, setValue } = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    register("myFile");
  }, [register]);

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.name, e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    alert(`Your file name: ${data.myFile.name}, size: ${data.myFile.size}`);
  };

  return (
    <StepsProvider>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <MySteps onInputChange={onInputChange} />
      </form>
    </StepsProvider>
  );
}

const MySteps = ({ onInputChange }) => {
  const { next, prev } = useSteps();

  return (
    <Steps>
      <div>
        <h1>Step 1</h1>
        <input type="file" name="myFile" onChange={onInputChange} />
        <button onClick={next}>Next</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>Step 2</h1>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </Steps>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-wozniak-of14l?file=/src/App.js

#### Multiple `form`s in each step

If you want need to have a form inside each step, you can pass the step's data up to the parent when upon step's form submission. Still the parent has the form state so it can handle when all the steps completed

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import { Steps, StepsProvider, useSteps } from "react-step-builder";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const formState = useRef();

  const onStepComplete = (data) => {
    formState.current = {
      ...formState.current,
      ...data
    };
  };

  const onComplete = (data) => {
    onStepComplete(data);
    const {
      name,
      myFile: [file]
    } = formState.current;
    alert(
      `Your name: ${name} Your file name: ${file.name}, size: ${file.size}`
    );
  };

  return (
    <StepsProvider>
      <MySteps onStepComplete={onStepComplete} onComplete={onComplete} />
    </StepsProvider>
  );
}

const MySteps = ({ onStepComplete, onComplete }) => {
  return (
    <Steps>
      <Step1 onStepComplete={onStepComplete} />
      <Step2 onComplete={onComplete} />
    </Steps>
  );
};

const Step1 = ({ onStepComplete }) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const { next } = useSteps();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    onStepComplete(data);
    next();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <h1>Step 1</h1>
      <input type="file" {...register("myFile")} />
      <button>Next</button>
    </form>
  );
};

const Step2 = ({ onComplete }) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    onComplete(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <h1>Step 2</h1>
      <input type="text" {...register("name")} />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-leaf-6gzoj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: pls help me fix in in multiple files i have to complte this by today if i have to split it into multiple compoents it will take time to change the ui

Answer (score 0):

Passing down the function and tracking changes at parent level is not a great idea. `react-hook-form` provides a form context option which allows you to do this independently. Such that errors, onChange are handled in each step separately. But when you need to submit the data you can get all of those in the parent component.

Refer to this documentation: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext/

**Note:** Many people make the mistake of placing the FormProvider inside the parent component. Remember that FormProvider should wrap the Parent component as well.